# Deleting the duplicate records, by comparing it with a max value in another column - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id  | rem_id |max_val
--  | ------ |------
1   | 1      | 7
2   | 2      | 6
3   | 3      | 1
4   | 1      | 1
5   | 2      | 1
6   | 3      | 1
```

In the above table I need to remove the duplicates from the rem_id column with min val in the max_val column

```
id  | rem_id |max_val
--  | ------ |------
1   | 1      | 7
2   | 2      | 6
3   | 3      | 1
```

Comment: If same rem_id exists in 3 rows, how many do you want to keep - 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

This will delete all but the highest valued `max_val` for each `rem_id`, or multiples of the same `max_val` by deleting those with a higher `id`:

```
delete t
from t 
  left join t as i
    on i.rem_id = t.rem_id
    and (i.max_val > t.max_val
      or (i.max_val = t.max_val and i.id < t.id)
      )
where i.id is not null;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/QKIK17666

returns:

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | rem_id | max_val |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |      1 |       7 |
|  2 |      2 |       6 |
|  3 |      3 |       1 |
+----+--------+---------+
```

Comment: You can't specify target table 'userRank' for update in FROM clause . I am getting this error

Comment: @Puhal Converted to a self join instead of `exists()`, my apologies.